# my array value found but does not match in table value value

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I don't know. why is my value match. I have User table value and is being print my data. but that I am match my from current date to next date so don't match some value employee dob and my date.
I don't know. why is my value match. I have User table value and is being print my data.

```
$dob = User::find() -> select(['employee_dob']) -> asArray() -> all();

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');
$curdate = date('Y-m-d');
$dateArray = [];

for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) {
    array_push($dateArray, date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+'.$i.
        ' day')));
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dateArray);
echo "<br />";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dob);
echo "<br />";

if (in_array($dateArray, $dob)) {
    echo "right";
    die;
} else {
    echo "false";
    die;
}
```

Comment: **in_array** Checks if a **value** exists in an array. You are checking **array** inside **array**

Comment: how to check inside array

Comment: Update your question with sample data of both array

Comment: actually i want to show my upcoming birthdays of users from current date to next 15 days

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your $dateArray is in array of array format.

What you can do is,

Print that array as in_array checks array values.

After that, iterate that array.

Good Luck!

Comment: array to string conversion

Comment: "array to string conversion"
Have you echoed your array?

Use this,

echo '<pre>'; print_r(); echo '</pre>';

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show upcoming birthdays of users from current date to next 15 days. Directly get it from database with where condition. Simply do following

```
 $dob = User::find()->select(['employee_dob'])
                    ->where(DB::raw('employee_dob >= NOW()'))
                    ->where(DB::raw('employee_dob <= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)'))
                    ->asArray()
                    ->all();
```

It will returns only birthdays of users from current date to next 15 days

Comment: how to change date format of array date than foreach loop

Comment: Will you give example what you want exactly?

Answer (score 0):

**Month & Day**

```
$monthDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d', date('m-d'));
$startDate = $monthDate->format('m-d');
$monthDate->modify('+15 days');
$endDate = $monthDate->format('m-d');
```

**Query**

```
$dob = User::find()
   ->select(['employee_name', 'DATE_FORMAT(employee_dob, "%d-%m-%Y") as dob'])
   ->where(['>=', 'DATE_FORMAT(employee_dob, "%m-%d")', $startDate])
   ->andWhere(['<=', 'DATE_FORMAT(employee_dob, "%m-%d")', $endDate])
   ->asArray()
   ->all();
```

**Output**

```
[
    0 => [
        'employee_name' => 'Insane'
        'dob' => '09-09-1993'
        ]
    1 => [
        'employee_name' => 'Skull'
        'dob' => '03-09-1999'
    ]
];
```